# import file took time and code coming after fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Im loading a config file that defines all my urls. 
My problem is when I run my code I obtain an error saying :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'SERVER' of undefined

Here is my code

```
import cfg from '../local_config'

console.info(cfg); // this is returning an ampty object

export const SERVER_URL = cfg.EXTERNAL_URLS.SERVER;
```

but if I run cfg.EXTERNAL_URLS.SERVER using the google chrome console (after getting the error) I got the result...

I have the feeling that importing my "local_config" took time to load and so I got the error, how may I avoid this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that the problem - `cfg` must not be populated immediately. To solve it, export a *function* that, when run, returns the desired property:

```
import cfg from '../local_config'
export const getServerURL = () => cfg.EXTERNAL_URLS.SERVER;
```

You should try to avoid interactions between modules before the entry point starts running in earnest, else you'll run into race conditions like these. The entry point should be the ultimate source of all interactions between modules.

Comment: This is a tricky solution, very nice :) but what changed when transform the export from simple export to an export of a function ?!

Comment: Yes, you'll have to call the function explicitly now, rather than simply referencing a (possibly mutable? avoid mutable exports) value.